# Want to change opacity on hover to css background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the image to be with black opacity, and on hover on exact a red it to become simple circle like on image, please explain how to do it.
Example picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhqlujyapihti71/h3uU2ZHpggU.jpg?dl=0

```
<div class="row">
            <div id="machinery">
                <h3 class="text-center" id="textPart">Модель  составляющих завода</h3>
                <a href="recycling.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="recyclingPart" data-namepart="Переработка"></div></a>
                <a href="cutting_lines.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="cuttingPart" data-namepart="Резка"></div></a>
                <a href="aging_silos.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="firstAgingPart" data-namepart="Выдержка сырья"></div></a>
                <a href="moulding.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="blockMouldingPart" data-namepart="Блок-формовочное оборудование"></div></a>
                <a href="expanding.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="expandingPart" data-namepart="Предвспениватели"></div></a>
                <a href="aging_silos.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="secondAgingPart" data-namepart="Выдержка сырья"></div></a>
                <a href="moulding.php"><div class="partOfMachine" id="shapeMouldingPart" data-namepart="Фигурно-формовочное оборудование"></div></a>
            </div>
</div>
```

My css is

`#machinery{
        width: 1140px;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: url(../img/zawod.jpg);
    }
        .thisPart{
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 1px black;
        }
        .partOfMachine{
            position: relative;
            width: 130px;
            height: 130px;
            border-radius: 100px;
            display: inline-block;

        }
        #recyclingPart{
            top: 170px;
            left: 50px;
        }
        #cuttingPart{
            top: 245px;
            left: 110px;
        }
        #firstAgingPart{
            top: 45px;
            left: -10px;
        }
        #blockMouldingPart{
            top: 115px;
            left: 50px;
        }
        #expandingPart{
            top: 155px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        #secondAgingPart{
            top: 65px;
            left: 200px;
        }
        #shapeMouldingPart{
            top: 160px;
            left: 170px;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I cannot find where the image is in your code. However, the general way of doing it is by adding a img:hover element in your CSS.
For ex.
if your html has

```
<img id="stackoverflow" src="Path" alt="Incase image fails to load">,
```

then you can add this in your CSS,

```
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

or

```
#stackoverflow:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: the image is in css as background image, and i want to reduce opacity of exact areas of picture div, if you use dropbox link, i think you will understand what i want to make, thanks

Comment: @BayramMuhiyew : Oops, sorry, understood now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, You can try to use something like this:

example: http://jsfiddle.net/9b2kL9zw/

First of all we create common container, we will use it as containing block for image and circle. Then we set image as a background for our #img div , then we set the same image for div that represents circle. After that we set opacity in #img div (if div that represents circle will be inside the #img div, it will gets opacity set by its parent, and we don't want that at all) and centralize the circle div as we want it to appear.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="img">
    </div>
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #container {
   height: 500px;
   width: 400px;
   margin: 2% auto;
   border: 1px solid #5970bb;
   border-radius: 3px;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.50);
   padding: 5px;
   position: relative;
}

 #img {
background: url(http://s14.postimg.org/cdkclcbep/cat.jpg) left top no-  repeat;
  height: 500px;
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0.2;
}


#circle {
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: url(http://s14.postimg.org/cdkclcbep/cat.jpg) center top no-repeat;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: in your example i see that in the circle there is the same picture but small, what i want is just that when you hower on exact parts of picture in the circle area becomes with no opacity, thanks